# Ajax post treatment of returned data

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to proxy a function so that I just replace part of the page instead of reloading the whole page.

```
<div id="content" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div class='contentitem' id='restart' style="margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 100px; margin-bottom: 100px; display:block;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><p style="font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold;"><%=translate([==[Loading...]==])%></p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//jquery library 
// released under BSD license
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var content = $("#content");

    $(document).ready(function(){   
        content.load('/cgi/b/sfltr/cfg/ div .contentitem', function(content) {
        $(this).find('tbody').each(function(){
              $("span:contains('Content Based Filtering')").closest("table").remove();
          });
        document.getElementById("restart").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
        //alert('Load was performed.');
    });
    });

  //intelligent version of submitform: will only refresh what is needed:
   (function() {  
   // proxying...
   var proxied = submitForm; // keep a copy of original method
   submitForm = function(theForm, actionNo, flags, primkey, confirmMsg, anchor, eval_code, customP) {
   //potential issue with the switch language... I think actionNo = 0 means reload.
   //alert('gotcha');
   // the following code is identical to what is in util.js
   //customP is only for restore page to upload config file to GW
    var VALIDATE = 0x01;
    var CONFIRM  = 0x02;
    var EVAL     = 0x04;

    if (flags && (flags & VALIDATE))
      if (!validate(theForm, actionNo)) return false;
    if (flags && (flags & CONFIRM))
      if (!confirm(confirmMsg)) return false;
    if (flags && (flags & EVAL) && eval_code)
      eval(eval_code);
    if (actionNo > 0)
      theForm.elements[0].value = actionNo;
    if (primkey)
      theForm.elements[1].value = primkey;
    var customArgs = new String("");
    if (g_state[TYPE].length > 0)
    {
      customArgs += "name="+encodeURIComponent(g_state[NAME]);
      if (g_state[KEY].length > 0)
        customArgs += "&" + g_urlArgs[KEY] + "=" + encodeURIComponent(g_state[KEY]);
    }
    if (g_state[TID].length > 0)
    {
      if (customArgs != "")
        customArgs += "&";
      customArgs += g_urlArgs[TID] + "=" + encodeURIComponent(g_state[TID]);
    }
    theForm.action += constructArgString(customArgs);
    if (customP)
      theForm.action += "&" + customP;
    if (anchor)
      theForm.action += "#" + anchor;
    //end of copy paste...


    //theForm.submit();
    //disable_fields(theForm);
        document.getElementById("restart").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("content").style.display = "none";

    //Now, I change the submit
    //theForm.submit(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: $(theForm).attr('method'),
            url: $(theForm).attr('action'),
            data: $(theForm).serialize(),
          datatype: "html"
            })
        .done(function (html) {
            //alert(html);
            var Test = -1;
            $("html").find('p').each(function(){
            //var result = $("this").find(":contains('You are being redirected')"); //check if tries to redirect
            Test = Test?Test:this.indexOf("You are being redirected"); //if we already found we skip.
            //TBD portuguese variant...
            alert(this);
            alert(Test);
            });
            if (Test==-1) {
                content.html(html);
            content.find('table').each(function(){
                $("span:contains('Content Based Filtering')").closest("table").remove();
                // Filtragem com base em conteúdo
                $("span:contains('Filtragem com base em conte')").closest("table").remove();
                $(document).find("#restart").css("display","none");
                content.css("display", "block");
            });
            }
            else
            {
             GoAndRemember('/PC_ov.lp', '');
            }
            })
        .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Unknown error:'+xhr.responseText);
        window.location.reload();
        });
  }
   return false;
   })();

</script>
```

When I submit the form using the function, the post works, and the 200OK contains the page I want to parse.

What I don't understand is:

1. Why I start loading the embedded script after (script of the code embedded in the 200OK),
   => Probably it is because I set this inside the div before I filter it out, but I thought it was the only way to make it. Should I create a new XHR object to store it in and then filter that object and set the DIV with the resulting .html()? If so could someone give a small example?
2. why I end up with an error because it overwrites the JavaScript I am using (it should be exactly the same code anyway)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here. It seems that when using the data type "html" it will always execute the embedded js. This solved the issue:
[prevent jquery ajax to execute javascript from script or html response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965111/prevent-jquery-ajax-to-execute-javascript-from-script-or-html-response)

The error is because some of the items that are necessary for the embedded JS to work are not available in this context.

Thanksa anyway.